# When I add a constant to all entries in a positive semi-definite matrix, is the resulting matrix again psd.?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let $k_{nm}=f(x_n,x_m)$ be a function generating the entries for a positive semi-definite matrix $K$ from two vectors $x_n$ and $x_m$. For example, $k_{nm}=x_n^Tx_m$ the inner product (also called the Kernel function and $K$ the Gram Matrix).

Now let $k'_{nm}=k_{nm}+\theta$ a new generating function for matrix $K'$ where $\theta$ a constant (scalar). Is this matrix again positive semi-definite or what are necessary restrictions on $\theta$ to have it psd. (e.g. $\theta>0$ I can imagine)?

Comment: The matrix $K$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $$\sum_{n,m}k_{nm}u_nu_m\geqslant0$$ for every $(u_n)$. Then, $$\sum_{n,m}(k_{nm}+\theta)u_nu_m=\sum_{n,m}k_{nm}u_nu_m+\theta\left(\sum_nu_n\right)^2$$ hence indeed, if $\theta>0$ then $K'$ is positive semi-definite. Simple examples show a similar result cannot hold for $\theta<0$.

Comment: @Did Perfect, thanks. You could turn it into an answer.